# Adding jQuery stops script from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm attempting to write a Chrome Extension that places a small script on the target pages, then performs a specific action against items on the page. Being new to Chrome Extensions, I've started small with a "Hello World" alert. This works fine, however what I actually want to do involves using jQUery against the objects.

Although my target page already imports jQuery, if I attempt to use it in my script, I get an exception that $ is undefined. However, if I attempt to import it myself, even the `alert` stops working.

Below is my code, can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "Simple Hello World Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:46950/"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", "popup.js"]
    }
  ] 
}
```

**popup.js**

```
$(helloWorld());

function helloWorld()
{
    alert("Hello World");
}
```

**Update**

Digging into Chrome://extensions, I realised that when I attempt to use the code below, the extension isn't being loaded into Chrome at all. If I try to manually load it again, I get the below exception:

> Could not load extension from ''. Could not load javascript '' for content script.

Comment: JavaScript functions are first order, you need to pass the function to jQuery's ready handler not invoke it. `$(helloWorld)` and _not_ `$(helloWorld())`

Comment: However, that particular issue isn't even reached due to `$` being undefined.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That doesn't appear to be the case. If I use `$(helloWorld);` nothing happens (in the scenarios where it normally works). If I add `$(helloWorld());` it works fine.

Comment: @ObsidianPhoenix if it works fine your way and not the other, then it is in fact not working correctly. `$(helloWorld());` might as well be written as `helloWorld();` because the `$()` part does nothing written that way.

Comment: @KevinB managed to get the extension working (about to post an answer), but even in the properly working version, it accepts both forms.

Comment: Sure, it will work, but the only reason it works is because jquery accepts `$(undefined)`. you're running your function immediately, rather than waiting for the dom to be ready. It's likely though that you don't need to wait for the dom to be ready anyway.

Comment: @KevinB ah, ok that makes sense. I'll bear that in mind then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928761/2505574) answer, which gave me some clues as to what was happening.

It appears that Chrome will not load in external resources in the extensions. Hence when I tried to load jQuery via google, it wouldn't load it, and crashed out the entire extension.

The reason I was trying to do this, was so as not to cause an issue where my multiple versions of the jquery conflicted between my extension and the target site. However, the answer indicates that the processes are essentially run in isolation, so it shouldn't have an issue. With that in mind, I've just added jquery into my extension manually and loaded it directly. this appears to work fine.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World",
  "description": "Simple Hello World Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
  {
      "matches": ["http://localhost:46950/"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "js": ["jquery-2.0.3.min.js", "popup.js"]
  }] 
}
```

Comment: You are correct; as extensions are sandboxed (unless you inject script into the page intentionally), you will not have any conflict issues.

Answer (score -2):

JQuery is expecting a dom element, so it is throwing an error.

It sounds like you are looking for something like $(document).ready():
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Replacing `$(helloWorld());` with `$(document).ready(helloWorld);` didn't seem to make any difference

Comment: `jQuery()` is expecting a dom element, a function, or a selector string, however in this case he is providing none of those to it.

Comment: No, the problem is he wasn't loading it correctly; extensions can't load outside resources.