# Content script inject jquery only when current tab has no jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I found out if I inject jquery from manifest, jquery will be injected even current page has already jquery. How can I avoid injecting duplicate js libs such as jquery?

```
"content_scripts": [
{
        "js": [
                "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                "scripts/content/inject.js"
              ],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content scripts are isolated from the webpage (sandboxed), so conflicts should not occur unless you are doing something advanced like manipulating the DOM to inject your scripts. If you use the manifest, conflicts shouldn't happen.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928761/3402854) for another answer to this question and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for Chrome's content script docs.